# XmlPullParser object doesnt read my second tag

Tags: java, android

The `xmlpullparser` doesn't read my second tag `term`. It always iterates two times: the first time, the inner tag is correctly identified as `appname`, but the second time, it's `null`.

```
public static List<Term> readConfig(XmlPullParser parser)
        throws XmlPullParserException, IOException
{

    List<Term> terms = null;

    parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, ns, "app");

    while (parser.next() != XmlPullParser.END_TAG)
    {
        if (parser.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.START_TAG)
        {
            continue;
        }

        String innerTag = parser.getName();

        if (innerTag.equals("appname"))
        {
            Logger.log("2");
        }
        else if (innerTag.equals("term"))
        {
            // terms = readTerm(parser);
            Logger.log("1");
        }

    }

    return terms;
}
```

My xml File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<app>
<appname>abdalla</appname>
<term>term1</term>
</app>
```

the exception

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: asset
at android.content.res.AssetManager.getAssetRemainingLength(Native Method)
at android.content.res.AssetManager.access$300(AssetManager.java:36)
at android.content.res.AssetManager$AssetInputStream.available(AssetManager.java:555)
at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:234)
at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.fillBuffer(KXmlParser.java:1496)
at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.readValue(KXmlParser.java:1340)
at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.next(KXmlParser.java:390)
at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.next(KXmlParser.java:310)
at model.XMLParser.readConfig(XMLParser.java:55)
at com.example.xmlparser.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:47)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the answer i fixed the above code with

```
    else if (eventType == XmlPullParser.END_TAG && tagName.equals(APP))
    {
        break;
    }
```

the complete code

```
public static List<Term> readConfig(XmlPullParser parser)
        throws XmlPullParserException, IOException
{

    List<Term> terms = new ArrayList<Term>();

    parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, ns, APP);

    int eventType = parser.getEventType();
    while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT)
    {
        String tagName = parser.getName();

        if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG && tagName.equals(APP))
        {
            // Attrubites
            String name = parser.getAttributeValue(null, "name");
            Logger.log(name);
        }
        else if (tagName != null && tagName.equals(TERM))
        {
            terms.add(readTerm(parser));
        }
        else if (eventType == XmlPullParser.END_TAG && tagName.equals(APP))
        {
            break;
        }
        eventType = parser.next();

    }

    return terms;
}
```